# What ordering is shown of friends who liked a photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-photos

I have a photo that received more than 3 likes. It says, "Adam, Bill, Charles, and x others like this".

Based on my notifications, I know that Adam, Bill, and Charles are the friends who most recently liked the photo (Adam being the most recent).

When I hover over "x others", it shows me a list of my friends who liked the photo, also in order of when they liked it.

However, when I click on "x others", the order is different. It's deterministic, but not based on any of the other factors that I would guess - edge weight (unless Facebook's edge weight algorithm is really bad) or date of Facebook account creation.

How is that list sorted?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience: The top 2 or 3 names (the ones that are shown) are the people you have the most interaction with.
When you click "others", the list is displayed in timestamp order.

I will do some checking/research and get back to you later, with a more sure answer.